# Beginner - Spring boot - how to print @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm learning `Spring Boot`.

What should I do to display param (city) from `@RequestParam` in the `show` method?

(I have two `html`. First with `form` and `button` to submit and second page to show the `String` value from `form`).

```
@GetMapping("/show")
public String show(@RequestParam ("city") String city, ModelMap modelMap){
    modelMap.addAttribute("article");
    System.out.println(city);
    return "article/show";
}
```

Comment: An answer will require knowledge of what you are using for the View layer e.g. JSP, Thymeleaf etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want show city inside a **view** you have to add the city to the model, something like:

```
model.addAttribute("city", city);
```

and inside the view `${city}`

Instead if you want print the parameter using the **console**, you can use a logger:

inside your controllore declare it in this way

`final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class);`

then inside the method:

```
 @GetMapping("/show")
public String show(@RequestParam ("city") String city, ModelMap modelMap){
    modelMap.addAttribute("article");

    logger.info("whatever you want "+city);

    return "article/show";
}
```

Comment: okok, thx bro ;] this is result: model.addAttribute("city", city);
and inside the view ${city}

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `modelMap.addAttribute("city", city);` and then retrieve it in the JSP / Thymeleaf side like `${city}`.